# possibility to change an image each time an application opens

Tags: php, image, random

thank you for helping me find a solution:

is there a possibility to change an image each time an application opens ???

I made this code

```
<img style = "position: relative; margin-left: 0; zoom: 100%; height: 100%" src = "images / home <? php $ random = rand (1,4); echo $ random;?> .png "alt =" [Random Image] "/>
```

but each image does not always change at each opening of the application sometimes it changes by another image sometimes not.

Comment: So you want to ensure a different image is displayed each time (never the same one twice in a row)?

Comment: you could store an image-id of the last image that was shown, so when you (re)open the app, you set a condition for it not to show that image, and randomly pick from the list of remaining images.

Comment: example of code plz??